# cannot resolve symbol android on TabHost methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to android development and i'm working on `TabHost` layout with three tabs so i made my xml file :

```
<TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ntm">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Present"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:text="Simple"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:text="Continuous"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:text="Perfect Simple"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:text="Perfect Continuous"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Past"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="NTM1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView25" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Future"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="NTM2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView26" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my code in the concerned activity to initialize the tabs :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time);

    }
    TabHost tab =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.ntm);
    tab.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("PRESENT");
    spec1.setIndicator("PRESENT");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.Present);
    tab.addTab(spec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("PAST");
    spec2.setIndicator("PAST");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.Past);
    tab.addTab(spec2);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tab.newTabSpec("FUTURE");
    spec3.setIndicator("FUTURE");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.Future);
    tab.addTab(spec3);
```

I get this error:

> cannot resolve symbol

On every methods like `tab.setup()` or all methods applicables on `TabHost` and `TabSpec` objects.

I've tried to copy/paste my code in the `main activity` and there I've got no errors but the application instantly crashes

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake, i had not put the initializing code into the method `onCreate` i've got no more errors